# PHP preg_match extract date/time inside <td> and convert into Unix time

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all, epoch

In my code I am trying to extract date/time only from `<td>` and then want to convert it into Unix time-stamp but I am stuck at extracting `preg_match_all()` function it won't show anything when I use `$result[0]` or `$result[1]`. I don't know why but when I dump the array I got following result:

My Array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <td align="left" valign="top">02 April 2017 | 05:55 PM</td>
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 02 April 2017 | 05:55 PM
        )

)
```

Here is my PHP code

```
preg_match_all('/<td align="left" valign="top">([^"]*)<\/td>/', $printtable, $result);
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: @chris85 got it works perfect but how I can convert the time into unixtime?

Comment: You may want to look at php function `date_parse_from_format`

Comment: sure that will be perfect

Comment: Why not simply use `strip_tags()` to get rid of the html tags?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware this option works great for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`preg_match_all` returns a multidimensional array, not a single element array like `preg_match`. Your capture group is `$result[1][0]` (the `1` index is the first capture group, all other indices are additional capture groups). To convert the string to unix time you can use `strtotime` with `str_replace` (to get it to a format `strtotime` can handle, you also could use `preg_replace` and strip all non alphanumerical/space characters).

```
echo strtotime(str_replace('|', '', '02 April 2017 | 05:55 PM'));
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/MsOlv